# Shaphiro's lemma over a field.

Tags: modules, homological-algebra, tensor-products

Maybe this is one of those obvious questions that indicates that I do not understand the definitions, but I need a bit of help.

Let $H\leq G$ and $M$ be a $H$-module, the induced module is defined as $\text{Ind}^G_H M=\mathbb{Z}G\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}H}M$, which is clearly a $G$-module. Shapiro's lemma states that:
$$H_\ast(H,M)\cong H_\ast(G,\text{Ind}^G_H M)$$
Now, suppose that $M=\mathbb{F}$ is a field, which is an $H$-module with the trivial action. What does shaphiro's lemma tell us in this setting? More preciselly, is there a way to understand $\text{Ind}^G_H \mathbb{F}$?

In particular I want to know if there is a way to relate $H_\ast(H,\mathbb{F})$ and $H_\ast(G,\mathbb{F})$, which I don't know wheter it is possible or not.

Comment: If you put the trivial action on a field $\mathbb k$, then inducing from $H$ to $G$ gives you the $G$-module $\mathbb k[G/H]$. By this I mean the $\mathbb k$-vector space with basis the $H$-cosets $gH$ and the obvious action of $G$.